unable to find kdevtmpfsi, kinsing, libsystem.so but they are inside /tmp of docker Postgres container, anything I can do to stop it?
I found the problem where I cannot locate kdevtempfsi kinsing with find / -iname "kdevtempfsi*" or find / -iname "kinsing*"


I know the problem came from docker postgres so I ls and chmod 000 of all of them but they are still running

